# How to construct a Minimal Excel-VBA Linked List without using custom Classes in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, linked-list

I am trying to construct a linked list in VBA that avoid:

1. the use custom classes.
2. any com objects such as dictionary

Below I have implemented (VBA, Excel 2016) such list using just VBA statements by using collections as a container for both the pointer and the value.

This implementation works well compared to the adding the containers to a collection (see testcollection function):

1. the LLadd function is capable of adding 5M items in under 15 s compared to 5s for adding 5M containers to a collection
2. itteration is fast <3s/5M items
3. the LLdelete function avoids the error 28 'out of stackspace error', but takes some time.

However, it has as issue in that the memory usage is rather high (5 milion elements ~1Gb) vs about 250Mb if you use a collection of only the values (note that is not what the testCollection function here does... that also uses 1Gb).

I have looked into linked lists, but I did not manage to find a minimal implementation that does not use classes.

*Is there a way to do this more memory efficient in VBA without resorting to classes and scripting objects?*

thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

' L is an array with 3 elements that provide access to the linkled list'
' it thus represents the list, but is actually a tuple with
'   L(0) the head or first element of the list'
'   L(1) then last element to be replaced with the next element added'
'   L(2) the current element (e.g when iterating)'

' each element C is a collection object with 2 elements'
'collections are able to be referenced (arrays are always copied)
'   C(1): the link to the next element'
'   C(2): the value'

Property Let LLadd(Lst, value)
    'force Lst to exist'
try: On Error GoTo catch
        If Lst(0) Is Nothing Then
catch:    Lst = Array(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim c As New Collection
    If Lst(0) Is Nothing Then 'add head twice'
        c.Add value
        Set Lst(0) = c
        Set Lst(1) = Lst(0)
    Else
        c.Add value
        Lst(1).Add c
        Set Lst(1) = Lst(1)(2)
    End If
End Property


'itterate through the items in de list, '
'maintain the index, and return value'
Function Iterating(L, Optional index, Optional value)
    index = index + 1
    If L(2) Is Nothing Then 'initialise iteration'
        Set L(2) = L(0)
        Iterating = True
        index = 1
        If Not IsMissing(value) Then value = L(2)(1)

    ElseIf L(2) Is L(1) Then 'exit loop'
        Iterating = False
        Set L(2) = Nothing
        If Not IsMissing(value) Then value = Empty

    Else
        Set L(2) = L(2)(2)
        If Not IsMissing(value) Then value = L(1)(1)
        Iterating = True
    End If
End Function

'This function cleans up after the list, error 28 if you dont...'
Sub LLdelete(Lst)
    Dim prev1, c
    Set c = Lst(0)
    While True
        Set prev1 = c
        Set c = c(2)
        prev1.Remove 2
        If c.Count = 1 Then
            Set Lst = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Wend
End Sub

Sub testLL()
    Dim L, i
    For i = 1 To 5000000
        LLadd(L) = i + 30
    Next
    i = 0

    Dim s, value
    While Iterating(L, i, value)
        s = s + value
    Wend
    Debug.Print i, s

    LLdelete L
End Sub


'add containers with links to a collection for comparrison'
Sub testcollection()
    Dim L As New Collection, i, c As New Collection, d As Collection
    For i = 1 To 5000000
        Set c = New Collection
        c.Add i + 33
        L.Add c
        If Not d Is Nothing Then d.Add c
        Set d = c
    Next
    i = 0

    Dim s, value
    For Each c In L
        i = i + 1
        s = s + c(1)
    Next
    Debug.Print i, s

    Set L = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Note 1**: the index in the iterating function is not really required, Its just there for future use

**Note 2**: the TestCollection function is for comparrison with a collection (its not quite comparable...)

**Note 3**: the ultimate aim is to allow have more control over for each loops (e.g reverse foreach, for each step 2 etc, for each with two lists at the same time (like Zip(list1,List2) in python)

Comment: Why the aversion to classes? In my mind this question boils down to "how can I implement this more efficiently using the same inefficient methods". VBA is not python, so the solutions in VBA will tend to be better using VBA constructs. Your "ultimate aim" would be fairly easy to implement (very efficiently) using a class with a configurable `NewEnum` function - ignoring that means ***fighting*** the language, not using it.

Comment: Thanks ComIntern you are ofcourse absolutely right. I am writing a tool to support students to solve chemical engineering problems numerically. I find a that the more modelues and classes there are, the more confused they get, so I am trying to "hide" code they dont need to see. 

In fact I have written a list class as you suggest, but it, crubles at large numbers e.g Col(key) and takes a very long time. The property with  'Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4' and the coll.[_NewEnum]  property provide a link to a collection, but gives no control during the for each loop

Comment: If `L` is a list, and a badly named list at that, with 3 elements, then why does the comment show `L(0),L(1) and L(3)` what happened to `L(2)`? You don't show how it's declared, so I don't know whether `L(0)` is out of bounds, or `L(3)` is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question, you are right there is no `L(3)`. Note that L is a tuple containing the head, and and current element of the list. Having pondered a bit, what I am really trying to do is to make an "itterator"  which I intend to be a low overhead, fast implementation that compares well with for each, allowing coding to happen out of view of the student each iteration.  L is a variant so as to minimise errors in declaring it by the students. The array L is generated on the line with label "catch" if its contents when passed into `LLadd`  is not an array with `L(1) is nothing`.